# Split JArray into multiple arrays

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to C# and I'm working on a small web API.
I have a big JSON Array with thousands of elements, I want to split it into multiple arrays with 1000 element each and the last array have remaining elements.

For example:
JArray jsonList; with 4475 records.
I want to split it into 5 arrays, 4 arrays will have 1000 each and the last array will have 475 records.

I have tried a lot of ways that splitting the array, but it's not working, I want to split json array of type JArray.

Comment: What have you tried and what is not working for you?